# How to access non-node items in a SmartArt in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a procedure, which I call when I stumble upon a SmartArt in a bigger Sub that changes the proofing language across the whole presentation:

```
Sub DealWithSmartArts(shp As Shape, lang As Long)
    Dim saNode As SmartArtNode
    For Each saNode In shp.SmartArt.AllNodes
        saNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
    Next saNode
End Sub
```

However, there are layouts (e.g. Alternating Hexagons), that have "decorative" shapes - these are not nodes, yet they can carry text and can have a proofing language set. Is there a VBA expression to get to them?

Comment: Small comfort, but I can confirm your results. Looks like a bug to me, I can't see any alternate method to reach the nodes without text.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a big issue, but it is bothering me. There has to be some way, right?

Comment: No, not necessarily. The VBA object model covers most program operations, but there are still items left out, like the nodes you discovered. When I want to change the language of a presentation, I unzip it and run a find and replace on the files using NotePad++. It would be possible to do this programmatically using Jan Karel Pieterse' OpenXML class. This is a free download for Excel, but it can be adapted for use in PowerPoint: https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007FileFormat02.asp. This class will unzip the files, then you can do a programmatic find and replace, then use the class to rezip.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look, but so far the VBA loops through available object model elements and it seems to be sufficient. I do see however a lot of interesting things to learn in this area (I have almost no programming experience and I rather re-use and adapt what I find, but I learn quickly with that)